# How to shake CCsprite in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have a `CCSprite` in my game, representing an egg. How do I go about shaking it? I tried the following, but without success:

```
id Runleft = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(244, 156)];
id RunRight = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(236, 156)];
[eggPlay runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:Runleft,RunRight,nil]]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a really nice shake for cocos2d-x here. It's a action and can be used with `runAction`

http://www.frozax.com/blog/2012/02/how-to-create-shake-action-cocos2d-x-source-code/

another shake action can be found on the cocos2d forums:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/20327

Answer (score 3):

```
id menuItem1ActDown= [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(0,-5)];
        id menuItem1ActUp= [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(0,+5)];
        id menuItem1easeDown = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:menuItem1ActDown rate:2];
        id menuItem1easeUp = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:menuItem1ActUp rate:2];
        id seq1 = [CCSequence actionOne:menuItem1easeDown two:menuItem1easeUp];
        [eggPlay runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq1]];
```

This will give you easing effect.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I done it with below code:

```
eggPlay.anchorPoint =  ccp(0.5,0.1);
 id rotateleft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:-10];
          id rotateright = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:10];
        [eggPlay runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:rotateleft,rotateright,nil]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move them left and right as below:

```
id menuItem1ActRight= [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(-7,0)];
id menuItem1ActLeft= [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.5 position:ccp(7,0)];
```